# Use objects from one django model to filter objects from another django objects

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I'm doing my studying project. I have 2 models:

```py
class RoutePoint(geo_models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False,
                                related_name='routepoints')
    point = geo_models.PointField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()


class Travel(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, blank=False,
                                related_name='travels')
    begin = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

First one contains geopoints for vehicle and date and time for vehicle getting there.
Second one countains the begining and the ending of the rides for vehicles.

I'm having some curl request with two fields - `start_date` and `end_date`, let's call it some kind request for report.

So, at first I need to get something like this:

```
SELECT vehicle_id, begin, end
FROM park_travel
WHERE begin > "2022-12-30" AND end < "2023-01-06"
```

I'll call it `result`.

And after that i need to get something like:

```
SELECT vehicle_id, point, datetime
FROM park_routepoint
WHERE vehicle_id = result.vehicle_id
  AND datetime > result.begin
  AND datetime < result.end
```

And I have to do it without raw sql...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query using [double underscore notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) and [`F` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```py
from django.db.models import F

route_points = RoutePoint.objects.filter(
    vehicle__travel__begin__lt=F("datetime"),
    vehicle__travel__end__gt=F("datetime")
)
```

then simply iterate over the `route_points` queryset:

```py
for route_point in route_points:
    print(route_point.vehicle, route_point.point, route_point.datetime)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's not doing exactly what I was looking for but your method is very interesting for learning something new. Those F-expressions are something!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the **Travel** Queryset:

```
start_date = '2022-12-30'
end_date = '2023-01-06'
travel_qs = Travel.objects.filter(begin__gt=start_date, 
end__lt=end_date).values('vehicle_id', 'begin', 'end')
```

Now you can use `travel_qs` to retrieve the Points from **RoutePoint**:

```
route_point_qs = RoutePoint.objects.filter(vehicle_id__in=travel_qs.values('vehicle_id'),
                                        datetime__gt=travel_qs.values('begin'),
                                        datetime__lt=travel_qs.values('end')).values('vehicle_id', 'point', 'datetime')
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
    vehicles_with_dates = travels.values('vehicle_id').annotate(min_dt=Min('begin'), max_dt=Max('end'))
    route_points = RoutePoint.objects.filter(
        vehicle_id__in=vehicles_with_dates.values('vehicle_id'),
        datetime__gt=vehicles_with_dates.values('min_dt'),
        datetime__lt=vehicles_with_dates.values('max_dt')
    )
```

It worked perfectly fine, thanks to Iqbal Hussain.